# Bukkit PlayerDeathEvent

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

why isn't this working? I don't get any response if I've been killed! So as you can see I have tested multiple ways. But no one is working.

```
package net.gameforce.testing;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;






public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {


@Override
public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this,this);
    getLogger().info("Testing Plugin Started");
}

public void onDisable() {}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("test");
    event.getPlayer().setExp(100);
}
public void onPlayerDeath (PlayerDeathEvent event){
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("send");
    event.getEntity().getPlayer().setExp(1000);
}

public boolean onDeath (PlayerDeathEvent event) {
    Player Player = event.getEntity();
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Player.getKiller().getDisplayName() + ", has killed you!");
    if (Player.getKiller() != null) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("No Player");
    }
    else {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("IDK");
    }


    return true;
}
}
```

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Use the @EventHandler annotation for the method. Also, are you registering your listener correctly (Check your server console to see if your message from onEnable is being printer by Logger)? Source: http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference#.40EventHandler

Comment: The message from the Logger is sended yes, the @EventHandler will i test out

Comment: (You also may want to send private messages to the player, as right now it's broadcasted which means everyone can read it. Might cause confusion in chat when one receives a bunch of "killed by xyz" at once.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotation from http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference#.40EventHandler

"Before this method can be invoked by Bukkit when the "Event" is fired, we need to annotate it. We do this with EventHandlers."

You've added this annotation to your onPlayerInteract method, but none of your others, such as your onDeath method. If your listener is setup correctly, adding the @EventHandler annotation to these methods will allow bukkit to correctly invoke them, like so:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath (PlayerDeathEvent event){
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("send");
    event.getEntity().getPlayer().setExp(1000);
}
```